# NuGet Source Control Integration

Tags: nuget

I checked out my project using git and saw the assembles I installed with NuGet as missing. I tried building and got a missing assembly error so I tried to re-add it with NuGet but NuGet says I have added that dll/reference to my project (it has a green checkmark).

I went into the options and checked get missing ref during build and did a rebuild and I am still getting missing asm errors.

How do I use NuGet with source control?

Answer (score 2):

Right Click Solution (and projects) -> Enable NuGet Package Restore

or...

Check the packages folder into source control.

YMMV, NuGet is terrible at integrating with source control.

Comment: +1 even though it didnt work for me. The restore seemed to do nothing

Comment: The restore has never worked for us, either :/ We don't use NuGet anymore because of this issue.

Comment: Oh :/ what do you do? stick dlls in a folder and have ppl copy what they need?

Comment: Check in each solution with a Lib folder at root that has the dlls. We also have a CommonBin on an internal build server which can be utilized via Reference Paths in the project settings. Unfortunately, these settings are stored in the .csprojuser file need to be added manually each time someone checks out a new solution.

Comment: We've just started using nuget for dependencies. Putting binary files into git is a worst practice. It works fine, across machines and on the build server. The UI solution above results in these entries in each project file in the solution:     <PropertyGroup><RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages> ... and   <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\nuget\NuGet.targets')" />

Answer (score 0):

What exact error are you seeing with package restore ?
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages - has more details around enabling package restore.

Answer (score 0):

[For the benefit of those who land here via a web search]
As of NuGet 2.0, "Restore Packages" is a step that can be performed by the build before attempting to build your solution:

See [this](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/msbuild-integrated) from official NuGet docs

Enabling package restore for a solution can be done through Visual Studio GUI and the changes made to the project are similar to what @Precipitous suggests in his comment. In essence you do this:
Right click on the solution in Visual Studio and click "Enable NuGet Package restore".